# yield break; - crazy behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, yield, break

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var test1 = Test1(1, 2);
            var test2 = Test2(3, 4);
        }

        static IEnumerable Test1(int v1, int v2)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        static IEnumerable Test2 (int v1, int v2)
        {
            return new String[] { };
        }
    }
}
```

"test1" seems to be an IEnumerable with v1 and v2 (params) as fields and "Test1" is NOT called.

"Test2" works a "designed" :)

whats going on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Test1` *is* called, but unless you iterate through the result, you won't hit a breakpoint on `yield break`.

Basically `Test1` is transformed into a state machine which implements `IEnumerable` for you... but all of the body of your method is inside that state machine, and unless you *use* the state machine by calling `GetEnumerator()` and then `MoveNext()` (or using a `foreach` loop) you won't see your body execute.

See my [general iterator article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx) and my [iterator implementation](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) article for more information, and also two of Eric Lippert's blog posts: [Psychic Debugging part one](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/09/05/psychic-debugging-part-one.aspx) and [Psychic Debugging part two](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/09/06/psychic-debugging-part-two.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Python, I'm going to point out that generators in Python work quite similarly to generators in C#. There's just the small difference that `yield break` alone can transform a C# method into a generator, while the Python equivalent of `raise StopIteration` won't.

```
>>> def f():
...     print "Beginning of generator"
...     if False: yield
...     print "End of generator"
... 
>>> it = f()
>>> it
<generator object at 0x94fae2c>
>>> it.next()
Beginning of generator
End of generator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```